# Numerical Differentiation with Time

Tags: vb.net, numeric, differential-equations

I'm trying to calculate speed from a distance/time data set by central differences but I found out that Date Class values aren't very friendly for arithmetic calculation.
Is there a way to substitute Date Class values to Decimal or Double?

Something between the lines of Date -> TimeSpan -> Double (just thinking on the fly here)

P.S.: I know about cubic spline derivative but I need to do in central differences.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What number do you want?

Comment: what about `DateTime.Ticks`?

Comment: you could use `dateDifference` function it is inbuilt in vb.